# Why my question is not getting any good quality of answers?

Tags: support

I asked [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35949/allah-name-in-clouds-is-allahs-miracle-or-are-a-part-of-random-design) question yesterday but still there is no good answer on it. But questions which were asked after my question got good answers (more than 1). Is nobody seeing my question that's why I am not getting answers ? Then what should I do now?

Comment: Maybe because it is opinion-based. Maybe because nobody who could give a good answer has read it yet  . . .